# How to name the TWebBrowser threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi, delphi-xe, twebbrowser

Once you call Navigate or Navigate2 on a TWebBrowser it creates at least 2 new threads which do not get freed until you destroy the browser.

What is the best way (if any) to get the thread IDs of threads spawned by the TWebBrowser instance in order to name them with TThread.NameThreadForDebugging?

Comment: Since this code is not delphi code at all (it's windows/internet explorer IShellDocView code) the best you could do is periodically scan and name such unexpected threads "AppearedAfterNavigate##" where ## is the unique numbering value you assigned yourself. I haven't ever succeeded even in doing that much, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no way to access the threads directly.  But you could enumerate the calling process's running threads with `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot()`, `Thread32First()`, and `Thread32Next()`, keeping track of any new threads you detect.  Another option would be to move your thread naming logic into a DLL so you can utilize its `DLL_THREAD_ATTACH` notification via Delphi's `DllProc/Ex()` callback(s).

Comment: All good suggestions. Mine class helper implementation available at http://pastebin.com/eNyftp4n